# Right-skewed distribution with mean equals to mode?

Tags: distributions, mean, skewness, mode

Is it possible to have a right-skewed distribution with mean equal to mode? If so, could you give me some example?

Comment: Take a suitable mixture of any finite-mean skewed distribution and any finite-mean unimodal symmetric distribution with the same mean.  All continuous examples and all discrete examples arise in this way.

Comment: @whuber, That's a great idea. If you have time, it would be terrific if you made a slightly more detailed answer out of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy examples come from binomial distributions -- which can hardly be dismissed as pathological or as bizarre counter-examples constructed *ad hoc*. Here is one for 10 trials and probability of success 0.1. Then the mean is 10 $\times$ 0.1 = 1, and 1 also is the mode (and for a bonus the median too), but the distribution is manifestly right skewed.

The code giving the number of successes 0 to 10 and their probabilities 0.348678... and so forth is Mata code from Stata, but your favourite statistical platform should be able to do it. (If not, you need a new favourite.)

```
: (0::10), binomialp(10, (0::10), 0.1)
                  1             2
     +-----------------------------+
   1 |            0   .3486784401  |
   2 |            1    .387420489  |
   3 |            2   .1937102445  |
   4 |            3    .057395628  |
   5 |            4    .011160261  |
   6 |            5   .0014880348  |
   7 |            6    .000137781  |
   8 |            7   8.74800e-06  |
   9 |            8   3.64500e-07  |
  10 |            9   9.00000e-09  |
  11 |           10   1.00000e-10  |
     +-----------------------------+
```

Among continuous distributions, the Weibull distribution can show equal mean and mode yet be right-skewed.

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely helpful! I will also look into the Weibull distribution you mentioned.

Comment: By the way, do you know some other continuous distribution with finite support that can exhibit the same property?

Comment: @DonTawanpitak A quick numerical search for the Weibull only revealed one solution: $\alpha = 3.3125, \beta = 1$ where $\alpha$ is the shape and $\beta$ is the scale. The mode and mean are then $0.897186$. But this Weibull isn't terribly right skewed (its skewness is $0.074$).

Answer (score 4):

If the distribution is discrete, sure. It's easy. For example, a distribution with probability mass function

- $P(X=0) = 0.36$
- $P(X=1) = 0.40$
- $P(X=2) = 0.13$
- $P(X=3) = 0.10$
- $P(X=4) = 0.01$

is right (i.e. positively) skewed and has both a mean and a mode of 1.

Comment: Is this suggesting that *discrete* distributions, as opposed to *continuous* distributions are more likely to exhibit this property? There seems to be a strong argument for that.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. I'm just saying it's easy to come up with an example (which is all the OP asked for) of a discrete distribution with that property.